# How to read all items from firebasestore database. in kotlin

Tags: python, java, android, kotlin, mobile

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ieyk.png)

Please help me! I really need for help. I am a junior developer from cambodia. I use android studio for build app for project at school. This problem it really effect for my project. So I can not do this.

Answer (score 1):

To read all items from Firebase Firestore database in Kotlin, you can use the following steps:

- Create a reference to the collection that you want to read.
- Get a snapshot of the collection.
- Iterate over the snapshot and get the data from each item.

The following code you can see how to read all from users collection.

```
val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
val usersRef = db.collection("users")

usersRef.get().addOnSuccessListener { snapshot ->
    for (document in snapshot.documents) {
        val user = document.toObject(User::class.java)

        // Do something with the user data.
    }
}
```